# Programmatically minimize all windows in OS X that have a certain title?

Tags: windows, macos, mac

I have various windows with the same title "MyTitle" across different running applications, which also have other windows with unique titles.

Is there a way I can programmatically cause all of these windows to minimize in an equivalent way to clicking the yellow minimize button?

Answer (score 2):

To go across all applications you will need to enable “GUI scripting” and use *System Events*.

Open the **Universal Access** preference pane and make sure “Enable access for assistive devices” is checked.

Then this AppleScript should be close to what you want:

```
set searchString to "whatever"
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with aWindow in ¬
        (get windows of (application processes whose visible is true) ¬
            whose name contains searchString)
        set aWindow to contents of aWindow
        if aWindow is not missing value and ¬
            (exists attribute "AXMinimized" of aWindow) then ¬
            set value of attribute "AXMinimized" of aWindow to true
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: I get: `error "Can’t get attribute \"AXMinimized\" of {}." number -1728 from attribute "AXMinimized" of {}` on Mavericks.

Comment: @e40: Try changing `(get windows of …)` to just `(windows of …)`.

Comment: That worked!!  Thanks!  I really appreciate it.  I'm a noob to applescript and I was banging my head on this one.

Answer (score 0):

This can likely be done with applescript.  I know that you can minimize a single application with this code.

```
tell application "Safari"
set miniaturized of window 1 to true
end tell
```

You can probably select the windows based on their title, you should be able to use the same "set min..." command though.